# Vue, changing the name of an input via list item click

Tags: html, vue.js

I have an input that I'm using in relation two an unordered list with two list items, which is in place, but I"m trying to figure out how I can change the input name/id with the click of one of the list items.

The items are not links or buttons, so I just want to be able to click the item text and if 'Public' is clicked, the input name would become public, if 'Internal' is clicked I would want the input name to be internal

I'm using Vue which may have some better options, but basically I just want to send the name of the input later on in an ajax call and I only want the name to be determined by the click of a list item potentially with a default.

What is the best way to achieve this with Vue being used?

```
<div class="row notesInput">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="tabs">
              <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
                <li>Public</li>
                <li>Internal</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" name="public">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First step: use component data to your advantage

You can simply store the desired input `name` attribute in the component data, e.g. `inputName`. Then, use `v-on` to bind a click event listener to your elements, so that whenever they are clicked, you invoke a method that updates the `inputData` property of your component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:  {
    inputName: '',
  },
  methods: {
    setInputName(str) {
      this.inputName = str;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row notesInput">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
          <li v-on:click="setInputName('public')">Public</li>
          <li v-on:click="setInputName('internal')">Internal</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-bind:name="inputName">
        <br />
        Input name attribute is: {{ inputName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Better: Use `v-for` to generate list items dynamically

If you don't want the manually provide the argument to the method, there's an easier way: you simply create a list of allowed names in the component data, too, and use `v-for` to generate the list dynamically:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:  {
    inputName: '',
    allowedNames: ['Public', 'Internal']
  },
  methods: {
    setInputName(str) {
      this.inputName = str.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row notesInput">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
          <li
            v-for="(allowedName, i) in allowedNames"
            v-bind:key="i"
            v-on:click="setInputName(allowedName)">
            {{ allowedName }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-bind:name="inputName">
        <br />
        Input name attribute is: {{ inputName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Even better: if there is no one-to-one correspondance between list item text and the desired name attribute

This can be useful in the case when, for example, you want the text to read `Public` but the name attribute to be another value. Instead of an array of strings, you can use an array of objects:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:  {
    inputName: '',
    allowedNames: [{
      label: 'Public (or any other arbitrary text you like)',
      name: 'public'
    }, {
      label: 'Internal (or any other arbitrary text you like)',
      name: 'internal',
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    setInputName(str) {
      this.inputName = str;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row notesInput">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
          <li
            v-for="(allowedName, i) in allowedNames"
            v-bind:key="i"
            v-on:click="setInputName(allowedName.name)">
            {{ allowedName.label }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-bind:name="inputName">
        <br />
        Input name attribute is: {{ inputName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```